# Add new column to data.table using conditional lookup from another data.table using R

Tags: r, data.table

I have the data.table `dt` as follows -

```
dt = structure(list(date = structure(c(18904L, 18904L, 18904L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), exp_date = structure(c(18915L, 19013L, 19377L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), days_remaining = c(11, 109, 473), year_remaining = c(0.0301369863013699, 
0.298630136986301, 1.2958904109589)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

    date   exp_date days_remaining year_remaining
    1: 2021-10-04 2021-10-15             11     0.03013699
    2: 2021-10-04 2022-01-21            109     0.29863014
    3: 2021-10-04 2023-01-20            473     1.29589041
```

To table `dt`, I want to add a rates column from the interest rates table called `rates_dt`
Here is the interest rate data.table `rates_dt`

```
rates_dt = structure(list(index = structure(c(18900, 18901, 18904, 18905, 
18906), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date", class = "Date"), `1_MO` = c(0.07, 
0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.06), `2_MO` = c(0.05, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04
), `3_MO` = c(0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04), `6_MO` = c(0.05, 
0.05, 0.06, 0.06, 0.06), `1_YR` = c(0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1
), `2_YR` = c(0.28, 0.27, 0.27, 0.28, 0.3), `3_YR` = c(0.53, 
0.49, 0.52, 0.54, 0.55)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))

        index 1_MO 2_MO 3_MO 6_MO 1_YR 2_YR 3_YR
1: 2021-09-30 0.07 0.05 0.04 0.05 0.09 0.28 0.53
2: 2021-10-01 0.08 0.04 0.04 0.05 0.09 0.27 0.49
3: 2021-10-04 0.09 0.04 0.04 0.06 0.09 0.27 0.52
4: 2021-10-05 0.10 0.04 0.04 0.06 0.09 0.28 0.54
5: 2021-10-06 0.06 0.04 0.04 0.06 0.10 0.30 0.55
```

What I am trying to do is, if `days_remaining` is less than 30 days in `dt` table, then add a `rates` column looking up at column `1_MO` in `rates_dt` table. And similarly, if  days_remaining is 473 (since more than 365 days), then take the rates from column `1_YR` in `rates_dt` table.
The output should look something like this -

```
             date   exp_date days_remaining year_remaining rates
    1: 2021-10-04 2021-10-15             11     0.03013699 0.09
    2: 2021-10-04 2022-01-21            109     0.29863014 0.04
    3: 2021-10-04 2023-01-20            473     1.29589041 0.09
```

In actual data, the column `date` will have all the dates for the past year. So the solution I am looking for should use group by `date`.

I have tried to melt up the `rates_dt` and then do something as follows, but could not reach the desired solution -

```
dt[melted_rates_dt, on = c("date" = "index"), rates := value]
```

I will appreciate it if someone can provide any pointer on how to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: None of the `2_YR` rates are 0.09, so it looks like your expected output is inconsistent. Can you clarify?

Comment: Is `melted_rates_dt` just `melt(rates_dt, id.vars = "index")`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The 473 days interest will be 1_YR rate as this rate will be applicable from 1_YR to 2_YR. Hence the interest rate of 0.09 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a good case for `findInterval` and joining on the melted rates.

```r
library(lubridate)
periodtxt <- c("1_MO", "2_MO", "3_MO", "6_MO", "1_YR", "2_YR", "3_YR")
periodn <- c(1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 24, 36)
dt[, period := mapply(function(dt, exp) periodtxt[findInterval(exp, dt %m+% months(c(0, periodn)))],
                      date, exp_date) ]
#          date   exp_date days_remaining year_remaining period
#        <IDat>     <IDat>          <num>          <num> <char>
# 1: 2021-10-04 2021-10-15             11     0.03013699   1_MO
# 2: 2021-10-04 2022-01-21            109     0.29863014   6_MO
# 3: 2021-10-04 2023-01-20            473     1.29589041   2_YR
```

From here,

```r
melted_rates_dt <- melt(rates_dt, id.vars = "index", variable.name = "period", value.name = "rate")
dt[melted_rates_dt, rate := rate, on = .(date == index, period)]
#          date   exp_date days_remaining year_remaining period  rate
#        <IDat>     <IDat>          <num>          <num> <char> <num>
# 1: 2021-10-04 2021-10-15             11     0.03013699   1_MO  0.09
# 2: 2021-10-04 2022-01-21            109     0.29863014   6_MO  0.06
# 3: 2021-10-04 2023-01-20            473     1.29589041   2_YR  0.27
```

(I am still not sure how you got `0.09` out of the `2_YR` data, so I'm offering it as-is until I understand better your third row of expected output.)

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans, its a neat solution. I think you meant 36 months instead of 26 for 3 Years.

Comment: Haha, yes, typo. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elegant and efficient code @r2evans. Actually, I've been going through it to try to understand it better (and to learn!) but the use of `exp` is still a bit mysterious to me. Could you please comment a little bit your code for a non-initiated like me. Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: `exp` is the second argument of the anonymous function used with `mapply`, which takes the first `date` and first `exp_date` and does something with them; then it does the same thing with the second values of each variable, etc.

Comment: O.K. thank you very much for this clarification. So if I understand correctly, `findInterval(exp, dt %m+% months(c(0, periodn)))` calculates the difference between `exp_date` and `date` (expressed in 0 to n months) and returns the index corresponding to the value of the vector `periodn` equal to this difference.

Comment: Moreover, if I understand correctly, the difference is calculated between the end of the month following the month of `exp_date` and the end of the month following the month of `date`.In other words, for line 1 of `dt`, this is subtracting 2021-11-30 from 2021-11-30 which is 0, hence the index 1; and for line 2, this is subtracting 2021-11-30 from 2021-02-28 which is 3 (month), hence the index 4. 
Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Not quite. [`findInterval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) has two arguments: the data (`exp` here) and a vector of cut-bins. It finds in which "bin" `exp` fits, where the bins are: now, +1 month, +2 months, +3 months, etc. `findInterval` will return a integer index within `periodtxt`. See `findInterval(1:10, c(0,3,6,10))` to try to see what's going on there.

Comment: O.K. That's it! I have (finally!) figured it out thanks to your clarifications. Thank you again for your patience and kindness.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I suggest:

**REPREX**

```r
library(data.table)

# Join between dt and rates_dt
z <- rates_dt[dt, on = .(index = date)][, c(1,9,10,11,2:8)]


# fill 'rates' column with multiple nested 'fifelse' (i.e. dedicated ifelse for data.table) and delete unnecessary columns
z[, `:=` (rates = fifelse (days_remaining <= 30, `1_MO`, 
                           fifelse(days_remaining > 30 & days_remaining <= 60, `2_MO`,
                                   fifelse(days_remaining > 60 & days_remaining <= 365, `3_MO`,
                                           fifelse(days_remaining > 365 & days_remaining <= 730, `1_YR`, `3_YR`)))),
          `1_MO` = NULL, `2_MO` = NULL, `3_MO` = NULL, `6_MO` = NULL, `1_YR` = NULL, `2_YR` = NULL, `3_YR` = NULL)]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The output:

```r
z
#>         index   exp_date days_remaining year_remaining rates
#> 1: 2021-10-04 2021-10-15             11     0.03013699  0.09
#> 2: 2021-10-04 2022-01-21            109     0.29863014  0.04
#> 3: 2021-10-04 2023-01-20            473     1.29589041  0.09
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows -

```
melted_rates_dt = melt(rates_dt, id.vars = "index")
dt[, duration := fcase(days_remaining < 30, "1_MO",
                            days_remaining < 61, "2_MO",
                            days_remaining < 91, "3_MO",
                            days_remaining < 181, "6_MO",
                            days_remaining < 365, "1_YR",
                            days_remaining < 730, "2_YR",
                            days_remaining < 1095, "3_YR")]
    
dt[melted_rates_dt, on = c("duration" = "variable", 
                           "date" = "index"), rates := value]
```